# Javascript regex in with special character in between

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello can anyone help my about regex. this is the string

```
((11A1:I19 + 11A1:K19 + 11A1:L19 + 11A1:I20 + 11A1:K20) - (11A1:N19 + 11A1:N20))
```

and this is the regex

```
/([0-9a-z])\w+:\w+([0-9-a-z])/g
```

I want to take 11A1:I19, 11A1:K19, etc.. and replace it with values so the string will look like this (1767+154+1123 - (151-17)) This is the full code

```
$f.each(function() {
    var formula = $(this).data("formula");

    var formula = $f.data("formula");

    formula.split(/([0-9a-z])\w+:\w+([0-9-a-z])/g)
        .forEach(function(el) {
             if (el) {
                 var hy = el.split(':');
              let v = $('[data-sheet="' + hy[0] + '"][data-cell="' + hy[1] + '"]').val();
             formula = formula.replace(el, v);
             }
        });

     console.log(formula)
     var result = eval(formula);
     $f.val(result)
});
```

Comment: What part of the original string do you want to extract? The regex only takes the first character ([0-9a-z]) and the last.

Comment: In this string... "((11A1:I19 + 11A1:K19 + 11A1:L19 + 11A1:I20 + 11A1:K20) - (11A1:N19 + 11A1:N20))".. I want to get these: 11A1:I19 11A1:K19 .... .... ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this (not tested with jquery)

```
$f.each(function() {
var formula = $(this).data("formula");

var formula = $f.data("formula");

formula.split(/([0-9a-z]+:[0-9a-z]+)/gi)
    .forEach(function(el) {
        if (el) {
            var hy = el.split(':');
            if (hy.length==2) {
              let v = $('[data-sheet="' + hy[0] + '"][data-cell="' + hy[1] + '"]').val();
              formula = formula.replace(el, v);
            }
         }
    });

 console.log(formula)
 var result = eval(formula);
 $f.val(result)
});
```

**Update:** After some more thinking, this code is more compact and possibly easier to read:

```
$f.each(function() {
var formula = $(this).data("formula");

var formula = $f.data("formula");

var Re=/([0-9a-z]+):([0-9a-z]+)/gi;
var hy;
var replaced=formula;
while ((hy=Re.exec(formula))!=null) {
    let v = $('[data-sheet="' + hy[1] + '"][data-cell="' + hy[2] + '"]').val();
    replaced = replaced.replace(hy[0], v);
}

console.log(replaced)
var result = eval(replaced);
$f.val(result)
});
```

For safety reasons, I would also check that `v` is a valid number before replacing it in the formula. That will avoid evaluating some code that might be a valid javascript expression with dire consequences. You can test it with:

```
if (isNaN(v+0)) continue;
```

Add it before replacing `hy[0]` with `v`.